# nginx-rtmp-module HLS with DVR

Tags: nginx, streaming

I've set up nginx-rtmp-module with HLS and I'm wondering if there's a way to set up DVR like Wowza's nDVR feature that lets you rewind a live stream, even to the very beginning of the stream. Right now I only get the most recent 40 seconds or so. Thanks!

(I gather it's possible from the comments here: http://nginx-rtmp.blogspot.ca/2013/02/multiple-locations-for-vod-in-098.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entirely possible, you just need to increase the HLS playlist length in your app config section. I've been using this myself and it works well!

For example if you'd like a DVR playlist of 30 minutes long, you'd put this inside your app section:

```
hls_playlist_length 30m;
```

See [nginx-rtmp-module hls directives](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#hls_playlist_length) for more info.

**Note**

The HLS player you use needs to support this. For example Flowplayer/JWplayer will however Safari (both Mac/iOS) will just play the live stream.

Comment: That works! Have you tried setting hls_playlist_length to something very large, say 4h? How does it affect performance? E.g. I think Wowza stores its DVR in memory, so longer streams can cause it to fill up heap space. Does nginx-rtmp-module also store the DVR in memory or is everything self-contained in those .ts chunks and the .m3u8 playlist?

Comment: Having had experience with Wowza, I can tell you it also stores its DVR chunks on disk. As you can imagine having hundreds of clients access these segments is horrible for performance. Nginx does the same. The solution is to create a RAM Disk and store them in "memory" by changing the HLS segment path.  `mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk` then point your nginx config so it stores HLS at `/mnt/ramdisk`. You'll find that your server will have no trouble serving lots of clients that way (provided you have enough RAM to store the segments!)

Comment: It also depends on the player. I used to have trouble seeking live video (VOD no problem) with Android version of JW Player(Windows version no problem), but newer version, e.g. jwplayer-8.1.4, has fixed this and seeks well on Android.